# Collections deleted from local db

Tags: mongodb, collections

I have a local Mongo DB and, all of a sudden, the collections have been deleted from the database. I have no idea how that happened.

Is there any way for restoring collections or anything else..?

Answer (score 0):

Is the oplog still available? The entire history of mongodb is stored in its oplog.You can replay the oplog to restore its data.
[Restore data from oplog](https://docs.bitnami.com/google-templates/infrastructure/mongodb/troubleshooting/restore-database-oplog-cluster/)

Comment: The oplog is a rolling record of database write operations for a replica set, but is unlikely to contain the entire history for an active deployment. The rare exception would be a case where all data has been freshly inserted and the oplog has never reached its target data size. Once data in the oplog capped collection reaches the target maximum size, the oldest entries are deleted to create space for new ones. Individual oplog entries contain an idempotent change document. Unless an oplog entry is for an insert (or a full document update), it will only include the changed fields.

Comment: More practically: if your oplog is 50GB and you have 1TB of data, the oplog only contains the last 50GB of changes. In the extreme case all of those changes could be single-field updates to documents (rather than insertions), which would leave no way to reconstruct full documents. The most reliable way to restore deleted data is from a backup.